# Setup teamcity to pull .asp/html files from TFS

Tags: asp-classic, build, teamcity

Currently, we have several build configurations for .net projects with Team foundation as the version control. Trying to create a build configuration for a classic asp site under TFS (no files that need to be compiled or .dlls). Not sure how to go about the steps in creating the build configuration (General Settings, Version Control Settings, Build Steps, etc..).

Using TeamCity Professional 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that I'm using:

General Settings:
The artifact path needs to map to a folder in your vcs. e.g.

```
%Sourcedirectory%/**
```

In VCS Settings, you should specify a branch to get e.g. `+:master`

In Checkout rules, you can limit what to get

```
+:Mycheckoutpath
```

Use a command line build step to copy files

```
(robocopy %SourceDirectory% %DestinationDirectory% /MIR /NP /NDL)  ^& IF %%ERRORLEVEL%% LEQ 4 exit /B 0
```

The variables in "%" are defined as parameters.
Use the `^& IF %%ERRORLEVEL%% LEQ 4 exit /B 0` to make sure to catch returncode 2 to be accepted (this is file overwritten)